# How to initialize field with default constructor using annotation

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

guys! Could you tell me please, how we can to initialize field, using annotation?
For example:
We have few custom classes: Foo; Bar. And in Main class, we entered two fields

```
public class Main {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
}
```

I want to create annotation, which helps to initialize these fields. In final result I want to see something like this:

```
@Initialize
Foo foo;
@Initialize
Bar bar;
```

Comment: What exactly should these annotations do? If you want a fixed initialization value, you can assign it directly. If you want to compute one, put it in the constructor. If you want some external injection, you need to have a DI provider.

Answer (score 1):

Annotation itself does nothing. It is just a metadata that can be retrieved using reflection. So, you can implement a kind of factory that receives class, creates its instance using default constructor, discovers the class's fields annotated with your annotation and sets the fields' values.

However I'd as the following questions before starting the implementation:

1. where will this factory find the values of `foo` and `bar` (probably from some kind of repository? Probably from JNDI?)
2. Do you really need this? Probably initialization using constructor is better. In this case you can mark all fields `final`, so you object will be immutable that have a lot of advantages
3. Are you probably re-inventing the wheel? Take a look on Spring framework. It does what you want and much-much more.